# Error in calling TaskGroup operator wrapped in function - AirflowException: TaskGroup can only be used inside a dag

Tags: python, airflow

Using Airflow v2.5.1

I'm omitting all the functions operators are calling since this is not a problem.

I have a following basic DAG:

```
with DAG('00_s3_file_processing_to_redshift', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None) as dag:
 
    start_task = DummyOperator(
    task_id='start_task',
    dag=dag
    )

    end_task = DummyOperator(
    task_id='end_task',
    dag=dag
    )

    process_files_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='process_files_task',
    python_callable=process_files_func,
    op_kwargs={'s3_bucket_name': s3_bucket_name},
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
    )


    start_task >> process_files_task >> end_task
```

`process_files_task` calls `process_files_func` which looks like this (shortened code for clarity):

```
def process_files_func(s3_bucket_name, **kwargs):
    with TaskGroup('process_files') as process_files_group:
        # s3_files = list_s3_files()

        list_s3_files_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id='list_s3_files_task',
            python_callable=list_s3_files,
            provide_context=True,
            dag=dag
        )         
        s3_files = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(key='s3_files')    
        print(s3_files) 
        
        previous_task = None
        for filepath in s3_files[1:]:
            print("xxxxxxxxxx  Working on filepath :", filepath)
            s3_file = filepath.replace("/", "_").replace(" ", "_").replace("-","_")[:-4]
            
            download_file_task = PythonOperator(
                task_id=f'download_file_{s3_file}',
                python_callable=download_file_from_s3,
                op_kwargs={
                    's3_bucket_name': s3_bucket_name,
                    'filepath': filepath,
                    'local_dir': 'temp'
                }
            )
            
            count_op_task = PythonOperator(
                task_id=f'count_records_{s3_file}',
                python_callable=count_records,
                op_kwargs={'filepath': filepath,
                           'local_dir': 'temp',
                           's3_file': s3_file
                }
            )
            
            create_temp_table_task = PythonOperator(
                task_id=f'create_temp_table_task_{s3_file}',
                python_callable=create_temp_table_function
                ) # other tasks go here...

    download_file_task >> count_op_task >> create_temp_table_task..other dependencies
```

Previously I didn't wrapp `TaskGroup` in function and it worked fine nicely iterating over files and processing them. I just used
`s3_files = list_s3_files()` to fetch list of keys.

In code above I decided to create task list_s3_files_task to have more control over
how keys are fetched from S3.
To do that I need kwargs for pulling xcom from `list_s3_files_task`. And to get kwargs I need to wrap everything in function.

All other tasks have no problem accessing and processing each others xcom but I don't know how to use xcom value from some task as iterator in TaskGroup...
Calling Python operator to call function which calls `TaskGroup` looks overly complicated...

This solution gives me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/airflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 175, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/data/airflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 192, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/data/airflow/dags/DoubleVerify/02_s3_file_processing.py", line 246, in process_files_func
    with TaskGroup('process_files') as process_files_group:
  File "/data/airflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/utils/task_group.py", line 122, in __init__
    raise AirflowException("TaskGroup can only be used inside a dag")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: TaskGroup can only be used inside a dag
```

Don't know why it's throwing that when whole thing is part of DAG?

Comment: you might want to use [dynamic task mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html)